# $q.allPromises returns an array but I only want one element, and not all

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-promise

Im using

```
$q.allPromises(http request).then (function (data) {
  //more code logic
})
```

It works the first time but I call this method 24 hours later and find that "data" is an array of Objects and it gets appended each time I call $q.allPromises with the new http json object.

How can I forget the old "object" in the array. I am pulling a json every 24 hours and only care about the json object I just fetched down. I want to disregard the json object pulled down from the previous http promise request but it seems like it keeps appending to an array

I tried adding

```
$q.allPromises(http request).then (function (data) {
  //more code logic
  data.shift ();
})
```

`shift()` is supposed to remove the first element off the array but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What is the purpose of using $q.all() when you clearly need only one promise to be resolved? Could you provide example of code? I assume that you're using AngularJS?

Comment: Yes, I'm using angularjs. I clearly only need to resolve only one promise. I am new to angular and saw an example online on how to resolve http json requests using promise so I copied it verbatim. I'm basically making a call to resolve http req to pull json and extract certain values to variable names.

Comment: I can post the code tonight, it's at home unfortunately

Comment: Sure. Let me know when you upload the code.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `$q.all`. The `$http` provider returns a promise all by itself:

```
$http.get({...}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.data) // this will print actual data
});

$http.post({...}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.data) // this will print actual data
});
```

`$q.all` is a special method for waiting on many promises to resolve before taking an action, like so:

```
var promiseA = $http.get({...}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.data) // this will print actual data
});

var promiseB = $http.post({...}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.data) // this will print actual data
});

var arrayOfPromises = $q.all([promiseA, promiseB]).then(function(arrayOfResults) {
  console.log(arrayOfResults); // this will print an array of the results of the http requests
});
```